# Не срабатывает отключение пароля пользователя Windows10

Tags: windows

Доброго времени суток всем.
За неделю два раза убирал пароль учетной записи windows10 на своем ноутбуке. Но каждый раз после выключения или закрытия крышки компьютера предлагается снова вводить пароль. Как надежно избавиться от ввода пароля? Что я делал. 
Заходил в командное окно (Win + R). Вводил команду Netplwiz. Убирал галку "требовать ввод имени пользователя и пароля", нажимал "применить". В окне "Автоматический вход в систему" (по инструкции http://gadgetick.com/newsnew-3103.html) вбивал пароль в "'пароль", "повторить пароль".
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А входишь локально или через учётку майков?

Comment: Вхожу локально под своего пользователя.

Comment: Попробуй `autologon` из пакета Марка Русиновича.

Comment: А кто такой Марк Русинович? Где могу достать его пакет? Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals

Comment: Спасибьо ! Но она не срабатывает для случая, когда машина выходит из спящего режима.

Comment: Тогда удали пароль из останстки управления компьютером.

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге помогло зайти в "Система" - "настройки" - учетные записи - параметы входа - никогда.